# returning multiple values in view django

Tags: python, django

I'm having some difficulty returning multiple values in my view. I can create a model, store the values in the model, and then return it, but this approach is not what I'm looking for because these values will be used once only.

Is it possible to return multiple values without storing them in a model?

For example, view.py:

```
loanAmount = request.GET.get('desired_loan')
repaymentTime = request.GET.get('repayment_time')
return render(request, 'blog/draw.html', "I want to return loanAmount and repaymentTime")
```

and then in Template, simply:

```
{{ loanAmount }}
```

How do I go about this? Any direction or help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand your sample code here. The third parameter to `render` is a dictionary, and you can have as many items as you like in it.

```
return render(request, 'blog/draw.html', {'loanAmount': loanAmount, 'repaymentTime': repaymentTime})
```

Comment: OK, sorry for the vague question. I did not know you could have many items. Thanks a lot, that answers my question. Do I call it by {{ loanAmount }}?

Comment: Yes, the key is what you'll use in the template i.e. 'loanAmount' - it doesn't has to be same as the variable name.
 'loanAm': loanAmount is also valid, in this case you'll be using loanAm in the template - {{ loanAm }}